# How to read multple files in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I want to read multiple files in Spring Batch. Currently, when using `MultiResourceItemReader`, it reads all lines without distinguishing between files. What I want is to process each file's lines separately and apply specific processing to each file based on the results of processing the lines. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried using `MultiResourceItemReader`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the type of your items implement `ResourceAware` and Spring Batch will set the current resource on every item. With that in place, items in the processor are aware of the resource they come from. That is the way to distinguish them.

If that does not help, then you can create a partitioned step with a `MultiResourcePartitioner`. This way, each worker step will handle a different file and you can apply the specific processing based on the input file.